# what is the minimal polynomial for $P $?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, minimal-polynomials

let  $P$ be the  operator on $\mathbb{R}^2  $   which project   each vector   onto the    $x- $axis ,parallel  to the $y$ axis :$ P(x,y)=(x,0)  $. What is the minimal  polynomial for $P $?

My attempt  : $ P$ doesn't satisfy  any constant polynomial  because  $P \neq 0$

since the operator $P$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$  so  $P^2(x,y)=P[P(x,y)]=(x,0)=P(x,y)$

$P^2 -P=0  \implies  P$ satisfies the polynomial $\lambda^2-\lambda$

Therefore the minimal  polynomial for $P $ is $\lambda^2-\lambda$

Is it true ?

Comment: Hey, I'm new to seeing this. What are the applications of translating an operator into a minimal polynomial?

Comment: @AlexanderConrad read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20the%20minimal,following%20three%20statements%20are%20equivalent%3A&text=%CE%BB%20is%20an%20eigenvalue%20of%20matrix%20A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. The ideal $\{f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x] \mid f(P) = 0\}$ is generated by the minimal polynomial of $P$.

So the only possibilities are $\lambda, \lambda -1$ or $\lambda^2 - \lambda$.

But the first two are clearly not possible, since $P\ne 0$ or $P\ne I$.